# liquibase changelogsync with spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, liquibase

I am migrating an existing database to be managed by liquibase.

I have the changelog already.
the application is a spring boot application and I updated the pom with `liquibase-core` and set up the spring liquibase properties.

I tested this against an empty database and works as expected and liquibase executes the changelog on application startup and maintains the `DATABASECHANGELOG` tables.

Now the issue that I am facing is that the database already exist in all other environments and I just want to baseline the changelog against these environments on the first application run with liquibase migration done.

I am aware that the liquibase `changelogsync` command is what I need and I am aware of the maven plugin that can execute it.

However, the maven plugin is not my first preference as I do not want to bring in another component and was hoping if there is a way to execute a `changelogsync` on application startup like how the `liquibase-core executes the liquibase on app startup` and control that with a spring application property.

I did a lot of research on this but only found answers using the maven plugin.

Comment: When we were need smth. similar we implemented [AbstractChange](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/master/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/change/AbstractChange.java) which was registering other changesets.

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov I posted an answer. That seems to be the way to go for me.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 independent issues in your topic.

1. Sync the existing databases with the new change log file. Liquibase must not try to run those changes on existing database, only on the new one.
2. Trigger liquibase each time (not only once), when the application starts up. Liquibase using `DATABASECHANGELOG` table identifies, what changes have been applied. You do not need to try it run only once.

For the first issue, you have 2 options:

1.1 Use `changeLogSync` or `changeLogSyncSQL`. It is reasonable only if you have a single client.

1.2 A better approach, adopt the new change log file (each statement) with `preConditions`, like:

```
<preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN"><not><tableExists tableName="settings"/></not></preConditions>
```

2. To trigger liquibase with Spring Boot during application startup, there are 2 articles on the official site:

[Using Liquibase with Spring Boot](https://docs.liquibase.com/tools-integrations/springboot/springboot.html?Highlight=spring)

[Using Liquibase with Spring Boot and Maven](https://docs.liquibase.com/tools-integrations/springboot/using-springboot-with-maven.html?Highlight=spring)

Comment: I think maybe I didnt mention this clearly. But I dont have issue number 2 as outlined in your answer. Only issue I have is with synching changelog against existing db. 

can you please clarify further on why 1.1 is only reasonable for single client and what do you mean by a client in this context.

Comment: you have both issues, #1 and #2, cause you ask `if there is a way to execute a changelogsync on application startup`. You consider this option, cause you want explicitly run `changelogsync`. You could avoid it entirely. I'll update my answer a bit later. I did exactly the same task, but only for JEE environment, not with Spring Boot.

Comment: I also mentioned `I tested this against an empty database and works as expected and liquibase executes the changelog on application startup and maintains the DATABASECHANGELOG tables.` 
I do not have issue 2 since liquibase is already running on startup as expected and checking against the changelog table to check if a changeset needs to be executed or not.

I just want to call the `changelogsync` command only when i set a specific property in `application-env.yml` as true. Because I want to control when liquibase blindly baselines the database using this property

Comment: and when this property is set to false, I want liquibase to run as expected and run only missing changesets.

Comment: I understand the solution you took by using a precondition to mark a changeset as executed on failure. It would work for me if I had a small changelog and if it only contains simple create/alter changesets. 
I currently have 10 microservices for which this needs to be done. Each microservice has its own changelog with an average of 20 changesets. 
It seems error prone to go with manually adding preconditions per your suggestion for that scale. Especially when `changelogsync` allows us to do that automatically by turning off the update command altogether and protecting existing database.

Comment: @MukulGoel, yes, it is the error prone solution, you need to be carefull. You have 2 choices. Either you try to automate running `changeLogSync`, which is just a command, so it is possible but with external tool. Or you wrapp each statement in your log with preconditions, but it is the standard liquibase solution, not other tools. In my case I had ~10 tables but even in this case, met some issues.

Answer (score 0):

I brought down the source for `liquibase-core` and found there are helper methods already in there to execute a `changelogsync`.

Basically the foundation of all CLI and plugins is the java based liquibase-core module so there are public methods to do all the possible tasks. They are simply not exposed to the spring module.

I tried the below changelogsync method and it seems to do what needs to be done.

[image: ChangeLogSync methods in Liquibase.java file]